# PayPal REST API Get Order Response for Venmo

Tags: paypal, venmo

Has anyone been able to successfully get a Venmo user's username when getting an order from the PayPal REST API?

We're getting a response with some of the user's information, but the `user_name` property ([docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get!c=200&path=payment_source/venmo/user_name&t=response)) doesn't appear to be included. Has anyone tried this before or have any tips for thing we can try to do to get passed this?

I would expect the `user_name` property to have a value as described in the documentation for the API.
I've tried looking through the response to see if the data is stored somewhere else in the object, but I've had no luck.